# using git-posh or/and oh-my-posh with Command Prompt(cmd, not Powershell) inside windows terminal

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, git-branch, windows-terminal

Recently switched to [new windows terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab), and after hours of searching on internet I was not able to find anything helpful, all what I want is to set up cmd inside new windows terminal to show git branches just like it's achievable for powershell.

eg like this [image]

I have been very comfortable with cmd especially with its ability to use additional linux commands and don't wanna switch to powershell only because of nice displays of git branches. [this](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-make-a-pretty-prompt-in-windows-terminal-with-powerline-nerd-fonts-cascadia-code-wsl-and-ohmyposh) is a source where everything is nicely explained for powershell, all I want is to do the same for CMD.

thanks in advance

Comment: If `powershell` works the way you want, why not just use `powershell`? What is the requirement to use `cmd`?

Comment: because powershell is not same as cmd, and I feel more comfortable with latter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to **use [Oh My Posh](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/)** for shell-prompt customization ***from `cmd.exe`***, the legacy Windows shell (citing from the [docs](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/installation/prompt), tab `cmd`, emphasis added):

> There's **no out of the box support** for Windows CMD when it comes to custom prompts. There is however **a way to do it using [Clink](https://chrisant996.github.io/clink/)**, which at the same time supercharges your cmd experience. Follow the installation instructions and make sure you select autostart.

> Integrating Oh My Posh with Clink is easy: create a new file called `oh-my-posh.lua` in your Clink scripts directory (run `clink info` inside cmd to find that file's location).
>
> `oh-my-posh.lua load(io.popen('oh-my-posh init cmd'):read("*a"))()`
>
> Once added, restart cmd for the changes to take effect.

As you later discovered, [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/issues/21) has background information on why native `cmd.exe` support isn't possible (even though Oh My Posh is generally shell-agnostic) and why third-party software is needed to make it work.

---

As for your comments re preferring `cmd.exe`:

> I have been very comfortable with cmd

Migrating from the shell one is used to a new one is undoubtedly a painful transition, but well worth considering in this case:

While not without its quirks, PowerShell is vastly superior in just about every respect to `cmd.exe`, and enables you to do things you simply cannot do in `cmd.exe`

> its ability to use additional linux commands

Linux (WSL) commands called from the Windows side are all mediated via *executables* (notably `wsl.exe` and `bash.exe`), which you can equally call *from PowerShell*.

Comment: Wow! ..did not know Clink existed. The auto complete is very cool!